# Scala MapReduce : [error] method reduce overrides nothing

Tags: scala, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I got stuck with this error, I wrote my TableReducer code like this:

```
class treducer extends TableReducer[Text, IntWritable, ImmutableBytesWritable]{
    override def reduce(key: Text, values: java.lang.Iterable[IntWritable], context:Reducer[Text, IntWritable, ImmutableBytesWritable, Mutation]#Context){
        var i=0
        for (v <- values) {
          i += v.get()
        }
        val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(key.toString()))  // be sure to comment on toString.getBytes
        put.add(Families.cf.bytes , Qualifiers.count.bytes, Bytes.toBytes(i))

        context.write(null, put)
    }
}
```

With this import:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get
import java.io.IOException
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase._
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client._
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io._
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce._
import org.apache.hadoop.io._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.ReduceContext
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer
```

But got this error:

```
[error] /home/ans4175/activator/scala-hbase/src/main/scala/com/example/Hello.scala:85: method reduce overrides nothing.
[error] Note: the super classes of class treducer contain the following, non final members named reduce:
[error] protected[package mapreduce] def reduce(x$1: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text,x$2: Iterable[org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable],x$3: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer[org.apache.hadoop.io.Text,org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable,org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable,org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable]#Context): Unit
[error]     override def reduce(key: Text, values: java.lang.Iterable[IntWritable], context:Reducer[Text, IntWritable, ImmutableBytesWritable, Mutation]#Context){
[error]                  ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

I don't know whats the problem. I have followed like this post
https://github.com/rawg/scala-hbase-wordcount/blob/master/src/main/scala/WordCountReducer.scala,
https://github.com/vadimbobrov/calc/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/os/job/InterpolatorReducer.scala

Thank you in advance

Comment: Add all imports to your code so that we can check what you're importing.

Comment: okay, i have added my import lines

Answer (score 2):

The error provides your answer. You've incorrectly declared one of the arguments.

The compiler has indicated that the third argument's type is:

```
Reducer[Text,IntWritable,ImmutableBytesWritable,Writable]#Context
```

Your override declares a method with a third argument of this type:

```
Reducer[Text, IntWritable, ImmutableBytesWritable, Mutation]#Context
```

Changing `Mutation` to `Writable` will allow the compiler to override the correct method.

Comment: Sir, still it doesn't compile.

Comment: Then the change you made didn't resolve the overloading. Maybe it requires a scala Iterable instead of a Java Iterable? Whatever the issue is, it will be resolved by making the arguments and return type agree with the base class signatures of the reduce method.

Comment: what is the base class signatures of the reduce method, sir ?

Answer (score 0):

when you override some method in a child class that means that same method must be there in parent class with same signature and your program is failing in that only.

this kind of errors typically indicates that signature of method in child is not matching with that in parent class, hence technically speaking you are not overriding anything and hence scala is telling you that

***[error] /home/ans4175/activator/scala-hbase/src/main/scala/com/example/Hello.scala:85: method reduce overrides nothing.

Note: the super classes of class treducer contain the following, non final members named reduce:***

Comment: but i'am overriding reduce method from TableReducer (HBase) which it is also extends from Reducer (Hadoop). Am I missing something important ?